# CakePHP URL rewriting in CentOS

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am new to CakePHP, when i am call with server name cake page is displaying but it is saying as  "I don't / can't use URL rewriting".

Help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. Turns out the .htaccess file was not getting copied alongside the `cakePHP` source.

This is a common issue when using the cp command or not having hidden files visible in a file browser, unless you copy the top-level directory.

Doing a direct copy of the file to my project folder fixed it for me without having to mess with my apache settings.

```
cp ~/git/cakePHP/.htaccess ~/project/folder/
```

May be it will help you.